# How to pass the textfield value to another class textfield in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I'm new to iphone, I'm using a UITextfield to enter the values and display in it, but i cannot pass the textfield value to another class.

```
classA
textfieldA.text=3
```

how to pass the textfieldA value to textfieldB ?

```
classB
textfieldB.text=
```

Comment: set that value in delegate variable and access that variable from ClassB.

Answer (score 1):

Easy :

**ClassA.h**

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject {
   UITextField* textfield;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) UITextField* textfield;
```

**ClassB.h**

```
@ClassA;
@interface ClassB : NSObject {
   ClassA* refClassA;
   UITextField* textfield;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain)ClassA* refClassA;  // you can also use assign instead of retain if you masterize the concept
@property(nonatomic, retain)UITextField* textfield;
```

**ClassA.m**

```
@synthesize textfield;

- (void) somefunction {
     self.textfield.text=@"3";
}


// and somewhere when creating ClassB
yourClassBObject.refClassA = self;
```

**ClassB.m**

```
#import "ClassA.h"

@synthesize refClassA;
@synthesize textfield;

- (void) somefunction {
     self.textfield.text = self.refClassA.textfield.text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value of text field in delegate variable by :

`appDelegate.textValueVariable = textfieldA.text ;`

Now You can access the delegate variable from ClassB by :
(write the below code in ClassB's `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`)

`textfieldB.text = appDelegate.textValueVariable ;`

Answer (score 0):

Take the TextfieldA value into a variable and then push the class to the another class and then with the class send your value and in the another class create a same type of variable and assign that value of the variable to the textfield similar like this--

```
Class A {
textfieldA.text=3;
int x;

anotherViewController *subControllr=[[anotherViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"anotherViewController" bundle:nil];
    [subControllr setY:x];
    UINavigationController *controller =[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:subControllr];
    controller.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque ;
    [subControllr setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
    [[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [subControllr release];
    [controller release];
}
```

Now `Class B{`
//create the same name variable as setY for passing the value

```
int y;
textfieldB.text=y;
}
```